# problems running programs using the command terminal

Tags: python, windows, command-line, syntax-error

So I'm determined to learn programming and I decided to start with Python and ChucK (audio language) but I'm having issues running things in the cmd terminal. I get Python to open in the terminal but when I try to run a program, I always get a syntax error indicating something wrong with the filename. I also encounter problems running ChucK through the command line. I can't further my learning like this and I need to resolve this. Running windows7 and python 2.7
Thanks!

![1]: http://imagebin.org/index.php?mode=image&id=163567

Comment: Paste the error that you are getting.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the link in the question is no longer valid. The question was not clear and lacks details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your link should be http://imagebin.org/163567

You're managing to run the Python interpreter, then trying to again run Python from within that interpreter. Instead of what you've done, try just `C:\Python27\python democodes.py` at the command line from whatever directory democodes.py is in.

Also, check out PyWin32, http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32

Latest 32-bit version: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build216/pywin32-216.win32-py2.7.exe/download

It includes a GUI python interpreter and editor called PythonWin that will be easier for you to use.

Comment: thanks for the reply.
i'm looking into your suggestions. I'm still getting the same error when I run a .py file the way you recommend. It's not just a python issue, (though it certainly is a big issue) it's also when I try to run ChucK through the terminal. So I think it's a bigger problem

Comment: The error your getting is because you're trying to run it inside the Python interpreter, not just in the terminal. What happens when you just open a terminal (NOT a Python interpreter) and run the command? Edit: If there is another error than the one you screenshotted, please add it.

Comment: I'm trying to run exercise 13 through the IDLE GUI which is
`from sys import argv

script, first, second, third = argv

print "The script is called:", script
print "Your first variable is:", first
print "Your second variable is:", second
print "Your third variable is:", third
`
the error reads:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\democode.py", line 3, in <module>
    script, first, second, third = argv
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
`
i copied the example verbatim from the pdf, so i don't see why I'm getting an error there.

Comment: of course the code is a mess because I can't skip lines.
pictures to follow soon
edit: http://sheddingbikes.com/LearnPythonTheHardWay.pdf

Comment: For that to work, you need to run something like `C:\Python27\python ex13.py a b c`. Python needs to be passed four arguments (the script and three more) if you're going to unpack four items from argv.

Comment: ...which needs to be done in the command line, which I still cant get to work. can you walk me through what you were describing earlier?

Comment: Run `cmd`. Change to the directory where your Python script is. At this point, you aren't in IDLE, you haven't run Python, or anything like that, you're just in the Windows command prompt. Then, type `C:\Python27\python democodes.py a b c d`

Comment: You're almost there. You typed `C:\Python27\python\democodes.py a b c d` instead of `C:\Python27\python democodes.py a b c d`. Notice the extra `\ ` you typed after python that shouldn't be there. `democodes.py` is not being run, it's being passed to Python as an argument. You also need to go to the directory folder where `democodes.py` is, not the `C:\ ` directory, so your first line should be `cd Documents` or something like that, not `cd C:\`, unless `democodes.py` is in the `C:\` directory.

Comment: http://imagebin.org/163645  ok this is a step in the right direction...edit: yeah I realized I made the mistake almost right after I posted, but I couldn't edit it (5 minute blocking rule and all) so I tried it again, without the nonexistant "root\python" directory. still an error, but it's more than I've had since starting

Comment: Great! That's actually my error, the arguments should actually be `democodes.py a b c` not `democodes.py a b c d` because that would be five, not four, arguments.

Comment: fantastic! it's running! I don't know why I was having problems with the directories, but things are working the way they should now. Thanks a ton! I'm going to try extrapolating this to run ChucK, hopefully that'll change some things